# Regular expressions and Chinese

Tags: android, regex, database

I have a database query based on user input, However if the user inputs any one common letter in the search the app will crash. but as the search also supports Chinese characters I can't simple block all one character searches.

How would I write a regular expression to check for a single English character but will not include a single Chinese characters?  "^(a-zA-Z){1}$" "^\w{1}$" do these include only english letters??

I'm thinking of using the regular expression like this, but any better solutions would be appreciated:

```
if(input.matches("^(a-zA-Z){1}$")
{
  //Show error
}
else
{
 //do query 
}
```

Comment: uhmmm can I suggest don't hack in a work around. fix the "my app will crash" problem?

Comment: @jb "but any better solutions would be appreciated"

Comment: Yes I should change the database query to have a limit 'LIMIT 50' , which would fix the crashing problem, but I would want to also use the regular expression so I can show a message to the user instead of them assuming the data doesn't exist.

Comment: ha good point. My advice is fix the app crashing part and allow one letter inputs. Without knowing any details though, I can't give any specific advice.

Comment: I guess what would be better is to compare the number of returned results with a 'COUNT' of the total number of results to show a message to the user if they are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely fix any crashes first. To distinguish between English and Chinese (CJK) characters, you can use character classes such as `\p{ASCII}`, `\p{Alpha}` for ASCII and `\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographs}` for CJK characters.