# How to filter Chinese characters with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to test a string.
The string can only contain English letters, number, hyphen and underscore.

previously I have one to test a string whether it only contains positive numbers(zero included); I used:

```
if(!/^\d+$/.test(number)) {
    alert('..bla');
} else {
    return true;
};
```

So I want a similar one. I have read:

[Regular expressions and Chinese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746607/regular-expressions-and-chinese);

and [Regex Letters, Numbers, Dashes, and Underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338044/regex-letters-numbers-dashes-and-underscores);

But these two does not seem to fix my problem.

```
    !/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+$/.test('_-bla')  // return false
    !/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+$/.test('_-bl我a')  // return false
    !/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+$/.test('_-bl我')  // return true
    !/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+/.test('_-bl我')  // return false
    !/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+/.test('_-bl我a') // return false
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067963/find-a-regular-expression-to-check-letter-chinese-character-and-slash

Comment: @Tun Zarni Kyaw Thanks. But that's a little difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `^[-\w]+$`. `\w` matches digits, alphabets, `_`.

```
/^[-\w]+$/.test('_-bla')   // true
/^[-\w]+$/.test('_-bl我a') // false
/^[-\w]+$/.test('_-bl我')  // false
/^[-\w]+$/.test('_-bl我')  // false
/^[-\w]+$/.test('_-bl我a') // false
```

Comment: Thank you. I added `$` but i forgot `^`. :p.   I do not have 15 reputation, so I cannot vote up. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking for this output. Add the caret (`^`) which means start of string and (`$`) meaning end of string to your regular expressions.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/.test('_-bla');    // True
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/.test('_-bl我a');  // False
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/.test('_-bl我');   // False
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/.test('_-bl我');   // False
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/.test('_-bl我a');  // False
```

You can just use `\w` instead which matches word characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`)

```
/^[\w-]+$/
```

Comment: Thank you. Your idea is the same with the one above. I will vote this up till I got 15 reputation. Thanks again. :)